# Nginx, getting upstream timed out error

Tags: nginx, timeout, 504

On my machine, there are multiple virtual hosts deployed.
I have a proxy server for these hosts, which redirects requests to the server.
However, I keep getting an upstream timed out error when I try to access one of the hosts. All the configuration settings are the same for all hosts, but this one particularly gives this error. The browser gives a 504 error, and the funny thing is that when I open multiple tabs with the same request, some of them load, but the other ones give 504.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. Moreover, home and enduser questions are off topic